# How do I trigger a function by clicking several buttons in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, button

The variables in this Javascript code represent buttons that once they have been clicked will trigger an animation within a function to be determined later. For the animation to be triggered, all 5 buttons need to be clicked. That’s the part I am struggling with.  The code represents the most I have been able to do so far (not very good at javascript). Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

```js
<script>
   var homework= document.getElementById("homerwork");
   var teeth= document.getElementById("teeth");
   var reading= document.getElementById("reading");
   var stuff= document.getElementById("stuff");
   var good= document.getElementById("good");
 


  homework.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
  teehth.addEventListener("click",righclick);
  reading.addEventListener("click", righclick);
  stuff.addEventListener("click", righclick);
  good.addEventListener("click", rigclick);

 function rightclicks () {
 
 

 //function that will trigger the animation//
  
  
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you try with homework.click();

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you want. If you want your function triggered within certain time interval, there is a js method `setInterval();`.

For example:

```
var a = function(){
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
}
setInterval(a, 3000);
```

The code above triggers the function every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You made some spelling errors(such as, function name). Added the runnable code. Here, all buttons are calling the same rightclick method. Hope this will help you to begin with.

```js
var homework= document.getElementById("homerwork");
var teeth = document.getElementById("teeth");
var reading= document.getElementById("reading");
var stuff= document.getElementById("stuff");
var good= document.getElementById("good");

homework.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
teeth.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
reading.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
stuff.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
good.addEventListener("click", rightclick);

function rightclick () {
    alert('hi');
    // function that will trigger the animation
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <button id="homerwork">Homework</button>
      <button id="teeth">Teeth</button>
      <button id="reading">Reading</button>
      <button id="stuff">Stuff</button>
      <button id="good">good</button>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute `clicked` of each html element in the click event handler.  Then, check if each button has the attribute 'clicked', and if so call `rightClicks()`

Something like

```
var ids = ['homework', 'teeth', 'etc'];

function rightClick(event) {
  event.target.clicked = true;
  var allClicked = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    if (!document.getElementById(ids[i]).attr('checked')) {
      allClicked = false;
    }
  }
  if (allClicked) {
    rightClicks();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a simpler or superior way of doing this, but by building off of your original code snip—firstly fixing typos, second adding to the rightclick() function—I've created a solution only using Vanilla JS. Hopefully this gives you something to work with!

```js
var homework= document.getElementById("homerwork");
var teeth= document.getElementById("teeth");
var reading= document.getElementById("reading");
var stuff= document.getElementById("stuff");
var good= document.getElementById("good");
 
homework.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
teeth.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
reading.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
stuff.addEventListener("click", rightclick);
good.addEventListener("click", rightclick);

function rightclick () {
  this.setAttribute("clicked", true);
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btns");
  var numButtons = buttons.length;
  var boolArray = [];
  for(var key in buttons){
    if(buttons[key].tagName == "BUTTON"){
      boolArray.push(buttons[key].getAttribute("clicked"));
    };
  };
  if(boolArray.length===numButtons){
    if(boolArray.includes("false")){
      return;
    } else {
      alert("all buttons clicked. go ahead with animation");
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button class="btns" id="homerwork" clicked=false>Homework</button>
      <button class="btns" id="teeth" clicked=false>Teeth</button>
      <button class="btns" id="reading" clicked=false>Reading</button>
      <button class="btns" id="stuff" clicked=false>Stuff</button>
      <button class="btns" id="good" clicked=false>good</button>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```